# ¿Cómo obtener el codigo de respuesta a una petición?

Tags: angular

estoy trabajando en un progama utilizando Angular 14, Cuando hago una inserción o actualización necesito capturar el codigo de la respuesta, ya que si no es exitosa notificar al usuario que vuelva a intentar.

Mi clase TypeScript en la que realizó la inserción es la siguiente:

```
this.tournamentService.register(tournamentn).pipe(switchMap(() => {
        return this.tournamentService.list();
      })).subscribe(tournaments => {
        this.tournamentService.tournamentChange.next(tournaments);
        this.tournamentService.messageChange.next('Ingresado Correctamente');
      });
```

Y mi clase service es la siguiente:

```
  tournamentChange = new Subject<tournament[]>();
  messageChange = new Subject<string>();

    register(tournamentn: tournament){
        return this.http.post(this.url, tournamentn);
      }
```

Esto es en el caso que todo resulte bien y se comunique con el servicio y guarde correctamente, es decir que devuelva 201:
[image: 201]

Ahora, van haber ocaciones en el que por A o B circunstancias devuelva otro estado distinto al de éxito:
[image: 400]

¿Cómo podría capturar el estado para así saber que mensaje mostrarle al usuario?

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el estado HTTP de cada petición, debes utilizar una de las opciones que se envian en cada método HttpClient que utilizas.

Esta opción es `observe`, la cual te permitirá mostrar la respuesta completa de tu servicio web, solo el body del response o solo eventos.

En tu caso utilizaremos `observe: 'response'` para mostrar el estado HTTP, utilizando el ejemplo que angular propone:

```
getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

Y esto lo puedes representar en el método `register`:

**Clase Service**

```
register(tournamentn: tournament){
 return this.http.post(this.url, tournamentn, {observe: 'response'});
}
```

**Clase Componente**

```
this.tournamentService.register(tournamentn).subscribe(response => {
    // Obtienes el estado HTTP
    console.log(response.status)
    
    // Obtienes el body de la respuesta
    console.log(response.body)
});
```

Puedes revisar la documentación de angular donde explican más sobre la lectura de una respuesta completa.

[Reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

[HttpResponse Class](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse)

[Angular HttpClient post](https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-httpclient-post#post)